# Subtotals in Power BI's waterfall chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm visualizing a P&L statement, and want to add subtotals for the Total Revenue, Total Costs, Operational Income etc.
but I don't find an option to do so, which is readily available in Excels' waterfall chart.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a hierarchy to your dataset, for example on the axis you can have Year, Quarter, Month. If you drill up or down you will always get the values for this hierarchy level (Totals per Year -> totals per Quarter -> totals per Month). So a subtotal from the year level would be the Quarter view when you drill down.

Or you can add a measure to your dataset. Something like one of this two:

```
Count Orders = CountRows(GroupBy('YourTable';[OrderNumber]))

Sum Sales = Summarize('YourTable', [OrderNumber], "Sum Sales per Order", Sum([SalesValue]))
```

You can drag and drop now the measure into the tooltip section of your visual.

Comment: @Strawberryshub, I cannot change the x axis categories, I need the breakdown there,also the P&L is only for a month. I even added a calculated column using Power Query to create buckets, expecting that the buckets could be added as subtotals but I failed to get the desired result